# WireShark: Only buffer the last 10 000 packets

Tags: wireshark

I am using WireShark to keep an eye on the traffic on two 10G ports, in real time. The problem is that there is so much traffic coming through the two ports that WireShark crashes within a minute.

Is there a way for WireShark to only buffer a small number of packets (say the 10 000 most recent), and discard anything previously captured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rotating log files to obtain something similar.

Using wireshark to keep a "live" view is/was not recommended anyway:
i'd rather use tcpdump writing on rotating/"sized" log files ( see tcpdump log options ) and wireshark -r to look ad the results.

Comment: Can I have rotating log files with wireshark?

Comment: yep! Somewhere in 'Capture options'. I can't screenshot it right now.